# Check alphabets in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a website in asp.net (C#) having two languages `"English"` and `"Persian"`. I have a search field in front end and I want to pick the English name when I do search in English and to pick the Persian name when I do search in Persian.

I have record in table in the following format:

```
===========================
   Name     |Persian Name|
===========================
Faridullah  |    فریدالله   |
```

I have a search field in front end. So I want to pick "Name" when I enter English alphabet and when the language is changed means when I enter Persian alphabet Persian name should be picked. so how could I do that in a query.

Comment: So you have a parameter for the current language?

Comment: فریدالله is Arabic btw.

Answer (score 8):

You can simple use `OR` in your `WHERE` clause in following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl
WHERE @name = Name OR @name = [Persian Name];
```

Or slightly shortened

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl
WHERE @name IN (Name, [Persian Name]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you also have a parameter for the current language:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl
WHERE
    ( @language = 'English' AND @name = Name )
OR  ( @language = 'Persian' AND @name = [Persian Name] )
```